# Constraint Layout with Data Binding is Unresponsive

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Problem that I'm facing is Constraint Layout is completely unresponsive. Margins are not shown, onCLick Handlers are not working. Below I've attached 2 images. Check it out. Where am I going wrong? Need more code..? I can update just let me know.

1. Row-Layout Class

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data>
   <variable
       name="lead"
       type="com.goplannr.model.LeadPojo" />

   <variable
       name="eventHandler"
      type="com.goplannr.fragment.contact.adapter.LeadClientRVAdapter" />

    </data>

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="8dp"
   android:background="@color/colorControlActivated"
   android:onClick="@{(v) -> eventHandler.onRowItemClick(v)}">

   .... got 4 items inside

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

   </layout>
   ```
2. RecyclerViewAdapter

   ```
    class LeadClientRVAdapter (private val leadDetailsList:ArrayList<LeadPojo>) :
   RecyclerView.Adapter<LeadClientRVAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
   val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
   val binding = RowLeadsClientsBinding.inflate(inflater)
   return MyViewHolder(binding)
   }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int = leadDetailsList.size

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(leadDetailsList[position])

   inner class MyViewHolder(private val binding: RowLeadsClientsBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
   fun bind(item : LeadPojo){
       binding.lead = item
       binding.executePendingBindings()
   }}

   fun onRowItemClick(v: View){
   v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_contacts_fragment_to_lead_details_fragment)
   }}
   ```

With Data Binding - [image]
Without -
[image]

Another point - I only have this dependency in Gradle -> dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

Nothing else

Comment: Your pictures are not viewable to everyone ..its asking for google account . Add image with imgur..

Comment: @ADM have a look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inflation code is incorrect. Use this

```
 val binding = RowLeadsClientsBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
```

Comment: binding.eventHandler = this@LeadClientRVAdapter should be inside MyViewHolder for clickListener to work.